# Get data and perform subtraction

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

On clicking approve  leave  I want the following :
Get number of days(for each employee) and apply user id by leave id that was post
Using apply user id i want to get leave balance(for each employee) from another table ,subtract number of days approved and leave balance then update the leave balance

I have the following code and i get an error
Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

SELECT `balance` FROM `emp_leave_balance` WHERE `emp_id` = `Array`

Controller:

```
 public function action(){
    if ($this->input->post('frm-action') =='approved'){
      foreach ($this->input->post('leave_id') as $leaveid) {
      if ($this->leave_model->approve($leaveid)){
           $emp_id =$this->leave_model->get($leaveid);
      $no_of_days =$this->leave_model->get_no($leaveid);
      $balance =$this->leave_model->get_bal($emp_id);
      $updated_balance = $no_of_days - $balance;
      $data = [
          'balance' =>$updated_balance
      ] ;
      $this->leave_model->update_leave($data,$emp_id);
      }
     
      }
        $this->session->set_flashdata('leave_approved','Leave is approved');
        redirect('leave/leave_list');
        exit();
    }

Model:


  public function get($leaveid){
      $this->db->select('apply_user_id');
      $this->db->where('leave_id',$leaveid);
      $query=$this->db->get('leave');
      return $query->result();
  }
  public function get_no($leaveid){
      $this->db->select('num_of_days');
      $this->db->where('leave_id',$leaveid);
      $query=$this->db->get('leave');
      return $query->result();
  }
  public function get_bal($emp_id){
      $this->db->select('balance');
      $this->db->where('emp_id',$emp_id);
      $query=$this->db->get('emp_leave_balance');
      return $query->result();
  }
  public function update_leave($data,$emp_id){

      $this->db->where('emp_id',$emp_id);
      $this->db->update('emp_leave_balance',$data);
      return true;
  }
```

View

```
<td><?php echo form_checkbox( 'leave_id[]',$Dleave->leave_id); ?></td>
```

Please help me out

I want to update each employee leave balance on approval

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the emp_id as the array in the sql. but sql wants that as the int value.

Go step by step and pass the right value in the sql.